# How to calculation below function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$arr = array(
    [
        'id' => '141',
        'text' => 'Abigail',
        'enable' => true
    ],
    [
        'id' => '142',
        'text' => 'Bernadette',
        'enable' => true
    ],
    [
        'id' => '143',
        'text' => 'Felicity',
        'enable' => false
    ],
    [
        'id' => '144',
        'text' => 'Irene',
        'enable' => true
    ],
    [
        'id' => '145',
        'text' => 'Rachel',
        'enable' => true
    ],
    [
        'id' => '146',
        'text' => 'Sally',
        'enable' => true
    ],
    [
        'id' => '147',
        'text' => 'Victoria',
        'enable' => false
    ]
);

foreach (array_reverse($arr) as $value) {
    if (!$value['enable']) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $value['id'].' --- '.$value['text'];
    echo "<br>";


    // First element 0
    // Second element 300
    // Third element 600

    // fourth element 0
    // fifth element 300
    // sixth elemtn 600

}
```

- First element 0
- Second element 300
- Third element 600
- fourth element 0
- fifth element 300
- sixth elemtn 600

I created a array. I need additions this array.
First element to add 0
second element to add 300
third element to add 600

and

next refresh

Comment: Ok. and what have you tried? Where are you stuck? "I need" isn't a question and this site isn't a free write-my-code service. We'll _help_ you with a specific problem you're having with _your_ attempt to solve this. See also the [tour], [ask] and how to create a [mre]. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: loops and variables which maintain a count are your friends here.